# fetching data from 2d arraylist from jsp to java in Struts2

Tags: jsp, arraylist, struts2

I am using Struts2 framework. Following is my code from jsp file.I have made getter and setter for the list. But the list returns null in my action class.
The data is fetched in form of 2d list. Data is displayed correctly.  I am able to view the data but not able to retrieve it. Could you provide solution why I am not able to get list in my Action class

```xml
  <s:iterator status="rowStatus" value="list1">
    <s:set name="currentFirstRowStatus" value='#rowStatus.index' />
    <div>
        <s:property value="list1[#rowStatus.index][0].eprocTenderNum"/>
    </div>
    <s:div id="divReport%{#currentFirstRowStatus}" cssStyle="display: block" >
        <table border="1" id="table1" style="">
            <th>Select <s:checkbox name="chkAllLines" onclick="makeAllLinesMandatory(this,1)" theme="simple"/> All </th>
            <th>col1</th>
            <th>col2</th>
            <th>col3</th>
            <th>col4</th>
            <th>col5</th>
            <s:iterator  status="rowStatus1" value="list1[#rowStatus.index]">
                <s:set name="currentRowStatus" value='#rowStatus1.index' />
                <tr>
                    <td><s:checkbox name="list1[%{#rowStatus.index}][%{#rowStatus1.index}].selectCheckBox" id="list1[%{#rowStatus.index}][%{#rowStatus1.index}].selectCheckBox"
                                    fieldValue="true" value="check1" theme="simple"/>
                        <s:hidden id="list1[%{#rowStatus.index}][%{#rowStatus1.index}].val1" name="list1[%{#rowStatus.index}][%{#rowStatus1.index}].val1"
                                  value="%{val1}" />
                    </td>
                    <td><s:property value="%{tag1}"/></td>
                    <td> <s:property value="%{tag2}"/></td>
                    <td><s:property value="%{tag3}"/></td>
                    <td><s:property value="%{tag4}"/></td>
                    <td><s:property value="%{tag5}"/></td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
            <tr> <td colspan="6"> <input type="button"  value="Approve" onclick='javascript:approve(<s:property value='%{#currentFirstRowStatus}'/>)'></td></tr>
        </table>
    </s:div>
    <br />
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: `List1` should be `list1`. `Val1` should be `val1`. Bidimensional lists are most likely not needed here (nor anywhere in a JSP)

Comment: Post your action code.

Comment: The name starts with list1 only. I need to fetch the value of val1 to my action class. I am able to view the data but when same is submitted to server then I list1 is fetched as null.

Comment: To fetch the value to the action class you don't need to write such complex expressions. The fact that it works unidirectional is strange isn't it?